# Specifying multiple SSL protocols to be used in winform application causes exception when calling webservice for TLS1.0 server

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, ssl, .net-4.5

I have a winform application built on .net framework 4.5 . I want my application to support multiple ssl protocols, hecnce I add the following code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
                                                  SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                                  SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                                  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 ;
```

But when I call a webservice hosted on a server using TLS 1.0 . I get the following exception:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I have tried different combination of SSl protocols, but it worked in three scenarios,

1. I didn't specify any protocol.
2. `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =SecurityProtocolType.Tls;`
3. `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =SecurityProtocolType.SSl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;`

So, is this a problem with server? or Am I doing something wrong?
Also, if I don't specify any SSL protocol, will it be able to call webservices hosted at a server using TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 ? Remember my application is built on .net framework 4.5 which supports TLS 1.0 by default.

Comment: Note that SSL/TLS support is entirely up to the SChannel system component which is tied to Windows version. And `Ssl3 | Tls` is the default, so 1) and 3) are the same. In my experience, it seems you can't specify multiple versions of TLS at the same time, since they are not compatible. Depending on your requirements, either stick exclusively with TLS 1.2 (the most secure ATM), or try a 1.0 fallback if 1.2 fails.

Comment: If I specify only Tls1.2 and Tls 1.1 , will it support both of the protocols?

Comment: As far as I know, no. The whole situation is a bit annoying :/

Comment: It is frustrating, if they allow us to specify multiple protocols then they should also support multiple protocols.No ,wonder most of the big companies use Java based frameworks.

Comment: The problem is, from a security standpoint, this is a good thing. You're not supposed to be able to renegotiate, because that destroys all the advantage you have from attempting to use a more secure protocol in the first place. If there's someone between you and the target server, *of course* he's going to try and pretend he only supports SSL3 - that makes it much easier to do a MITM attack. SSL/TLS is heavily built around trust - if you don't even know if the target server supports TLS 1.2 or not, you lost half the battle.